# Azure data factory - linked server by IP and port

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a linked server to an on-premise SQL Server database. For the port, we are using the non-standard 2232.

How would I enter this into the "Server name" field for the linked server?
Sample IP address: 123.456.789.001
Port: 2232

Server name: 123.456.789.001,2232 ?
Server name: 123.456.789.001:2232 ?

Is this even possible? Or do I need to have the instance running on the standard port 1433?

Comment: If you think my post helps you, you could mark it as answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You should use `ip,port` as Server name such as `123.456.789.001,2232`. I have tested this for you, it can work fine.

[image]